# What should I do with a freezer that has been infested with small flies and larvae?

Tags: cleaning, freezer

My condo has  been vacant for a couple of years, and I don't get over there very much to check on things. The electricity was turned off, and I figured I would leave it off, since it wasn't really needed at the time. O boy, I forgot about the refrigerator, and when opening the freezer, which is on top, there were hundreds of small flies and larvae crawling on a box of turkey burgers and coated with them!!! After the electricity was turned back on, the flies and larvae died, so now I need to clean it out. I'm overly conscious about germs as it is, and just want to throw the refrigerator out. The shelf in the freezer doesn't come out, so it's going to be hard to clean. There is a vent inside, probably with a fan in it, and there are dead flies laying around the vent holes. Does anyone have a suggestion before I throw the refrigerator out?

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn off fridge and open doors until it has warmed up
2. Remove everything you can from the fridge
3. Clean with diluted bleach (like 1/4 cup bleach per gallon of water)
4. Clean again with soapy water
5. Clean again with water
6. Dry it thoroughly

Don't worry too much about the vent and make sure that you keep all your foods stored in sealed containers especially in the freezer (mostly to prevent freezer burn).

Comment: Thank you kindly